# gulp watch not compile sass to css

Tags: css, sass, gulp, watch

I am beginner in using gulp, and i trying to use gulp sass and gulp watch to compile my sass file, but there is no css file created after running gulp watch command

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

//gulp.task('default', function () {
//    // place code for your default task here
//});
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);


gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
 return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

**the project hiererchy**

```
myProject
     |_ public_html
     |    |_ css
     |    |_ sass
     |    |_ js
     |    |_ index.html
     |_ node_modules
     |_ gulpfile.js
     |_ package.json
```

and when i run gulp

```
[21:37:26] Starting 'sass'...
[21:37:26] Starting 'watch'...
[21:37:26] Finished 'watch' after 7.01 ms
[21:37:26] Finished 'sass' after 29 ms
[21:37:26] Starting 'default'...
[21:37:26] Finished 'default' after 7.11 ?s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the file paths are wrong.

Instead of `./sass/*.scss`

try

`public_html/sass/*.scss/`

Notice that `./` refers to the current working dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have two tasks both called sass try removing the first one as you dont really need it. It's actually not great practise to have `./` at the start of your paths, try removing them too.

Your also missing a callback so try this.

```
gulp.task('sass', function (cb) {
 return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('css'), cb());
});
```